# We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code NOT_FOUND

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, libraries

I'm facing this issue while I'm running the script. one day before if was working fine for me.
I did clear all the cache of chrome browser and I tried another laptop also but the issue is as it is.
please help me to resolve the issue.

The code I'm running is:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Reporting Tools');
  menu.addItem('Create Unit Scorecards', 'HSIPScorecard2021CountryScripts.createInputSheets');
  menu.addItem('Notify Unit H&S Heads', 'HSIPScorecard2021CountryScripts.sendNotifications');
  menu.addItem('Consolidate Unit Data', 'HSIPScorecard2021CountryScripts.Consolidate');
  menu.addToUi();
}
```

Comment: is this intended to be an addon?

Comment: Is this `HSIPScorecard2021CountryScripts` the name of your library and has it been installed properly?

Comment: Related bug report on the Google Apps Script issue tracker: [Using a lib that has view permissions gives "a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code NOT_FOUND."](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183634726)

Answer (score 27):

I just ran into the same problem last week. After wasting a few day's time, I found it was caused by a reference to a library using development mode. Change it to a deployment version solved that.

Comment: For future viewers: This appears to still be a solution as of August 2021. Certainly, I had the same issue described by the OP and this answer resolved it directly.

Comment: Update April 2023; you can also overcome this by using an installed onOpen() trigger in the library.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the name of the library is correct you can write that like this:

```
function onOpen(e) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Reporting Tools')
      .addItem('Create Unit Scorecards', 'HSIPScorecard2021CountryScripts.createInputSheets');
      .addItem('Notify Unit H&S Heads', 'HSIPScorecard2021CountryScripts.sendNotifications');
      .addItem('Consolidate Unit Data', 'HSIPScorecard2021CountryScripts.Consolidate');
      .addToUi();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that need to be checked in order to fix this issue.

1. The Library reference should link to the Deployment Version and not to the Development Mode.
2. The Library file should not be restricted in case you are sharing the copy of the original file with somebody else.

Comment: Does it matter if they are a viewer or an editor on the file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error...
It appeared that the library (`HSIPScorecard2021CountryScripts` in your case) had a reference to another library (`BasicTools`).
From the account that owned both, it worked. However, from any other account, that error appeared. Even if Edit permission was given.

The solution was to move the functions from `BasicTools` to `HSIPScorecard2021CountryScripts` (and fix the functions calls).

So, in short, one more solution to try is to make sure the library you are using doesn't use any other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Using an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically) in the parent library (instead of `onOpen()` in the dependent script) also fixes this issue.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('exported.createDefaultMenuAndAddToUI')
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
  .onOpen()
  .create();
```

It will give you a new problem in that the menu item actions are outside of the dependent library scope. I manage referencing things that need to be accessed by both the library and its dependent scripts like this:

```
function getExports () {
  return {  
    /* TRIGGERS */
    hourlyCronTask, 
    createDefaultMenuAndAddToUI,
    /* MENU ITEMS */
    actionInitialHelp,
    ...
  };
}

const exported = getExports();
```

Then in dependent script `Code.js`

```
const exported = MyParentLibrary.getExports();
```

These need to be defined in a [hoistable function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) rather than a constant since only these are exposed to dependent scripts.