# What would be the best way to create multiple Google Apps Scripts for an organization?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have multiple Google Apps Scripts deployed as libraries and added into Google Sheets.

The problem starts when I share these sheets with other users.
To even let them see the user menu load, I needed to give them edit access to my library scripts. View only access wasn't enough. Then I got the following error message from them "Exception: Service Admin SDK API has not been enabled for your Apps Script-managed Cloud Platform project"

And I know I'm getting this for using function AdminDirectory.Members.insert(...);
I don't want add API privileges for them in GSuite.

The following oauthScopes are in use:

"oauthScopes": [
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member"
]

What I'm looking for is a solution to create these scripts in a way that I would able to add them to my Google Sheets, where user menu could be loaded from the scripts and called by users. All script code from the library/add-on (eg,: GSuite create new user / add user to group / open, edit docs / open, edit sheets) should be run through my credential, not with theirs. Users shouldn't be able to view/edit the libraries/add-on scripts' code.

The only code they should able to see and edit is the tiny onOpen script in the Sheet's script file. They have to have access to the script library / add-on but only to run it, call functions from it. They shouldn't be able to read and edit the library/add-on script code. Their code in the spreadsheet would be really small. Just an onOpen trigger which would load the menu from the script and give access to the main functions which could be called from the menu. Those would be public functions. The rest is private.

Script from Sheet
[image: Menu loaded from the script]

Library called "Script"
[image: Functions called by menu items]
This is how my script is loading the menu in Sheets and calls the functions through it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want users to execute a script to which they don't have access? That is not possible. You could display the menu without giving them access to the library if you [install](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) the `onOpen` trigger, but you cannot let them execute a function from the menu if they don't have access to the function code.

Comment: You could use a service account that impersonates you if you wanted them to execute functions that call Admin SDK, but they would need access to those functions anyway. If you provide more context about your situation and your goal, though, maybe a workaround could be found.

Comment: Sorry, if I couldn't explain clearly my plan. Of course they have to have access to the script library / add-on but only to run. They shouldn't be able to read and edit the library/add-on script code, like an application if you will. You can run the application but can't see the source code. Their code in the spreadsheet would be really small. Just an onOpen trigger which would load the menu from the attached library/add-on and give access to the main functions which could be called from the menu. Those would be public functions. The rest could be private.

Comment: The mail goal would be not let the scripts run under their credentials but the library's creator/user. Also the scripts has to do some work in the actual sheet and also access to other sheets and documents as well on the drive. Because I'm an admin I have access to everything. If a new user would like to use this sheet then I need to give them some API access, write access to other sheets and docs. I'm not sure if I can do this with libraries. Anybody knows that Editor add-on for Sheet would be a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

If I understand your situation correctly:

- You have an editor add-on through which you want to execute functions that access Admin SDK (via a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/menus)).
- You want users in your domain, which do not have privileges to access Admin SDK, to be able to execute these functions.
- You are a domain admin and can access the desired Admin SDK services.

You won't accomplish this by placing your code in a library, since there's no way to "delegate" the execution of a library function: the library function will run under the authority of the user executing the menu function.

#### Solution:

In that case, I'd suggest the following alternative:

1. Create a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account?hl=no#creatinganaccount).
2. Follow [this guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account?hl=no#delegatingauthority) to grant the service account domain-wide delegation, so that it can be used to impersonate any account in your domain: in this case, your account.
3. Import and use the library [OAuth2 for Apps Script](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2) in order to use the service account in your Apps Script project.
4. Use [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) to call your desired API, using the access token from the service account.

#### Code sample:

For example, if you wanted to call Directory API's [users.get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/get) to retrieve data from the user currently executing this, you would do something like this:

```
function getService() {
  const service = OAuth2.createService("Service account")
                    .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
                    .setPrivateKey(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY)
                    .setIssuer(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                    .setSubject(IMPERSONATED_EMAIL)
                    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
                    .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
                    .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user')
  return service;
}

function getActiveUserData() {
  const service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    const userKey = Session.getActiveUser();
    const url = `https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/${userKey}`;
    const options = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + service.getAccessToken(),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    }
    const resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    const userData = JSON.parse(resp.getContentText());
    return userData;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Iamblichus.

Yes, this would solve the excess API privilege of regular users. However you mentioned Editor add-on but all of my scripts are just plain libraries. And my biggest concern is in my situation, that I needed to share my code with 'Edit' privileges to see the functions working for them. By default read privilege should be sufficient, but then I'm getting the following error if I try to run the Script.loadMenu() function manually from the Sheet.

Comment: Error message:
"We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code NOT_FOUND"

With read access to the libs, they can read the library scripts and view the source code. But the code is not working anymore in the Sheet in this case.

Comment: I was able to make the library work with read only access, If I'm using a versioned number from it, not the development mode in appscript.json

    "libraries": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Script",
        "libraryId": "........",
        "version": "1..."
      }
    ]
The idea came from here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65611963/were-sorry-a-server-error-occurred-while-reading-from-storage-error-code-not)

Comment: Thank you @Iamblichus, 
I'm going to accept your answer as you helped how to use a service account instead of giving excess API access to users.

Comment: @gabriel7 Since you mentioned add-ons several times in your question, I thought you were using that. In any case, I understand that your issue is solved now, I'm glad that's the case.