# Web Application using a library shows We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code NOT_FOUND to some users

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, libraries

Same error message and slightly similar to [We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code NOT_FOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65611963/1595451) (simple onOpen trigger calling functions from a library), but in my case I had a web application. The solution from the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65773159/1595451), to use a version instead of the head deployment, doesn't apply as my web app was already set to use a library version. The problem appeared after doing a slight change to the library.

1. The web app was working fine, but I was required to make a change.

   - My web app uses global variables to handle several settings.
2. I made a change to the library and created a new version

   - The change was moving a literal string from one array to another array.
3. I updated the library version number in the web app.
4. The web app works fine for my account but not for other accounts

- I reviewed the library version number in the manifest, it was OK.
- Using previous library versions works fine

The web app uses a Google Cloud Standard Project, set for internal use only. The library is used by other Google Apps Script projects. It has multiple namespaces (`var myNamespace = ((ns) => { /** some stuff here */ return ns})({})`) most of them are focused on using a single service (FormApp, SpreadsheetApp, DriveApp), but only few are used on the web app.

I wasn't able to reproduce the problem, so I think that it's related to the specific projects. Disabling V8 implies too much work i.e. I used a lot `const` , `let`, arrow functions and other stuff unsupported by the old runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two workarounds solved the problem, none of them are "perfect".

1. Replacing the library by a copy (same code, different project URL / ID and version number)
2. Making a new web-app deployment (different web-app URL)

The main problem with the first is that I had to update other projects using the same library, the main problem with the later is that the new deployment has a different URL I had to notify the web app users the new URL, the might have to change their bookmarks / update their notes.

Finally I decided to use the second because there are other projects relaying on the library for sharing solutions settings shared through the library `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()`.

Comment: Hi @Ruben, thanks for haivng posted this. I got the same problem and was forced to re-deploy a library. Any idea why this might be happening? I mean it's great that we have a solution, but it'd be nice to be able to avoid this all togethyer :)

Comment: Hi @DmitryKostyuk . If you found this answer helpful  please upvote it. Regarding your enquiry, I have no idea but I guess  that some get broken on the Google side... I  think that there isn't yet a bug report on the issue tracker yet.

Comment: Upvoted Should we consider creating a ticket? I wouldn't know how to make them reproduce the problem though