# Script fails when triggered from google sheet drawing for a specific user, but works for other users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We have a Google Sheet that has a drawing pic that calls a script. It works fine for some users.

For one user, whenever the click on the drawing, the green bar says "Script is running" but nothing happens. When I look at the execution log, it says that the execution failed, but the user is not seeing a red error bar.

I suspect it has something to do with authorization for the script, but the pop up to select a Google Account to authorize doesn't come up.

Any advice on how we can reset one user's ability to trigger a script?

EDIT: Trying to running it from the code editor gives:
`We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code NOT_FOUND`

And resolving according to [We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code NOT_FOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65611963/were-sorry-a-server-error-occurred-while-reading-from-storage-error-code-not) still didnt work

Comment: Besides the `execution failed` error do you get any other error message or additional details in the execution log? Did the answer about authorizing the script by manually running it from the script editor worked for you?

Comment: I did get a cryptic message when the user ran it through the code editor: 
We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code NOT_FOUND

And tried to resolve it based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65611963/were-sorry-a-server-error-occurred-while-reading-from-storage-error-code-not but still didnt work

Comment: The question is missing relevant details and is currently not answerable. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try with the account of that user opening Extensions-Apps Script and running the script from the console. It should then ask the proper permissions and keep it usable from that moment on

Comment: I tried that, the problem seems to be related to libraries I use that were on development. I tried to fix it per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65611963/were-sorry-a-server-error-occurred-while-reading-from-storage-error-code-not but it's still not working :/